# Error a la hora de iniciar con un usuario en thunderbird

Tags: debian, dovecot, postfix, maquinas-virtuales

Estoy realizando una práctica de desplegamento web en una máquina virtual de Debian 11 y tengo que hacer lo siguiente:

*Que el servidor DNS disponga de un subdominio mail.tu-nombre.local. Crea un servidor de correo (Dovecot-Postfix) con dos usuarios que puedan enviar un correo entre ellos. Emplea Thunderbird como cliente de correo en el sistema principal.*

El principal problema que me encuentro es que a la hora de iniciar sesión en thunderbird con uno de los usuarios creados me reconoce el dominio pero no me deja acceder. Dejo imágenes para detalles:

[image: Configuracion dominio.local]

[image: Configuración zona inversa]

[image: Configuracion dovecot.conf]

[image: Configuracón .cf de postfix]

[image: Configuracion 10-auth.conf]

[image: Configuracion 20-imap.conf]

[image: Error del thunderbird]

Estaria sumamente agradecido si alguien me pudiera aclarar el problema

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! ESto no parece un problema de programacion. no?